# motion not starting as a daemon in 16.04

Tags: webcam

I have motion installed and starts OK manually,
It is enabled in /etc/default/motion.
But on a reboot its not starting

if I do `root@odroid64:/# systemctl start motion`:

```
root@odroid64:/# systemctl status motion
● motion.service - LSB: Start Motion detection
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/motion; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-02-11 16:28:03 GMT; 2 years 2 months ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 565 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/motion start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Apr 23 13:56:36 odroid64 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Motion detection.
```

```
root@odroid64:/# ps ax | grep motion

3489 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto motion
```

Strange, no process running.
Verified as I can't access the motion server .
Nothing in the motion.log, just previous entries from yesterday

```
root@odroid64:/# cat /etc/default/motion
# set to 'yes' to enable the motion daemon
start_motion_daemon=yes
```

any ideas, the device its on is a odroid C2 SBC 64bit

sorry formatting is awful, first time I've used this

---

**Update 1:**

In response to `systemctl start motion`
`journal -ex` shows :

```
Apr 23 17:19:22 odroid64 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Motion detection   
-- Subject: Unit motion.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- 
-- Unit motion.service has finished starting up.
--
```

```
root@odroid64:/# systemctl list-units --state=running | less
```

Shows no instance of motion running

```
root@odroid64:/# tail /var/log/motion/motion.log

[3] [NTC] [NET] [Apr 22 11:45:49] netcam_read_html_jpeg: Potential split boundary - 1447 chars flushed, 1 re-positioned.
```

That log entry is 7 hrs old, so nothing new, there is nothing in syslog.

`/var/log/faillog` is empty

Permissions on `motion.log` are 664
so it shouldn't crash for not being able to use its log file.
`motion.conf` is in `/etc/motion`  which is the default location.

I could start it on boot in `rc.local`, but I need to be able to use cron to 
to start and stop motion , which if I start in `rc.local` means an awkward script to get the pid, so it can be killed.

**Update 2:**

It looks like when motion is started by a user

```
sudo motion &
```

it is started by root

However, when started by `systemd` its started as `motion`

Both the config file `/etc/motion/motion.conf` and the log file `/var/log/motion/motion.log`
need to be in group `motion`.

Comment: Did you do `sudo systemctl enable motion` after install, or did you miss a step in the setup process?

Comment: I see the option to have it  start on boot by adding it to your startup applications! https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/motion

Comment: Then you have to create a service for it!

Comment: Click on the grey `edit` below your question to add pertinent information into it, or press the orange one here: [edit]

Comment: This problem still exists in Ubuntu 18 One hack is to do the following: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046980/motion-server-doesnt-start This is also documented as a bug here with another hack to fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/motion/+bug/294852/comments/4