# motion server doesnt start

Tags: server, video, cron, startup, webcam

I have a webserver with motion v 4.0, but motion doesnt start on boot, I have to tell it to start every time with `sudo motion -b` then everything is cool until I need to reboot. I have tried editing the config files, `/etc/motion/motion.conf` and  `/etc/defualt/motion`

to include the variable: `start_motion_daemon=yes`
which is supposed to start the procces at boot?

but the process in never running when I go to check it. I tried setting up rc.local, but it seems ubuntu is not doing that any more?

I tried enabling the service with systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl enable motion
motion.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable motion
```

but the service never gets enabled, or even turned on.
so then I looked in the logs:

```
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:10] v4l2_get_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:10] v4l2_get_capability: - STREAMING
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:10] v4l2_select_input: name = "Camera 1", type 0x00000002, status 00000000
[0:web_control] [NTC] [STR] [Jun 16 07:26:10] http_bindsock: error binding on 127.0.0.1 port 8080
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:10] v4l2_select_input: - CAMERA
[0:web_control] [NTC] [STR] [Jun 16 07:26:10] motion_web_control: motion-httpd thread exit
[1:ml1] [ERR] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:10] v4l2_select_input: Error selecting input 0 VIDIOC_S_INPUT: Device or resource busy
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:10] vid_v4lx_start: Using V4L1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:10] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1:ml1] [ERR] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:20] motion_init: Error capturing first image
[1:ml1] [NTC] [STR] [Jun 16 07:26:20] http_bindsock: error binding on any IPv4 address port 8081
[1:ml1] [ERR] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:20] motion_init: Problem enabling motion-stream server in port 8081: Address already in use
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:20] motion_loop: Thread exiting
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:20] vid_close: Closing video device /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:21] main: Motion thread 1 restart
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:21] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] vid_v4lx_start: Using videodevice /dev/video0 and input -1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] v4l2_get_capability: 
------------------------
cap.driver: "uvcvideo"
cap.card: "HD Webcam C615"
cap.bus_info: "usb-ff540000.usb-1.1"
cap.capabilities=0x84200001
------------------------
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] v4l2_get_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] v4l2_get_capability: - STREAMING
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] v4l2_select_input: name = "Camera 1", type 0x00000002, status 00000000
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] v4l2_select_input: - CAMERA
[1:ml1] [ERR] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] v4l2_select_input: Error selecting input 0 VIDIOC_S_INPUT: Device or resource busy
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Jun 16 07:26:21] vid_v4lx_start: Using V4L1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Jun 16 07:26:21] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
(END)
```

reading the logs, I would think the process is running, but it is not.

Per suggestion, I tried setting up a cron job, running `sudo crontab -e`
 and adding the line @reboot `/usr/bin/motion -b`

but on reboot, the motion daemon is still not running..

I just want to know the modern way to start this process on boot.
Ubuntu 18.04, LXDE.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this @j0h ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use cron @reboot

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add the line

```
@reboot   /path/to/bin/motion -b
```

Comment: does that work for cold boots?

Comment: yes it works at cold boot

Answer (score 0):

First, try to run it manually with `sudo -u motion motion`. If it works, then the problem is caused by systemd.

This is counter-intuitive, but with systemd you should set `daemon off` in motion.conf.

PS: The file `/etc/defualt/motion` is probably not needed in Ubuntu/Debian.